# How to mock several gets in fetch-mock?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, fetch, fetch-mock

I'm testing my react components and I want to mock several `get` operations. What I want to do is something like:

```
test(`Created correctly`, async () => {
    fetchMock.get(`*`, JSON.stringify(FIRSTGETOBJ));
    fetchMock.get(`*`, JSON.stringify(SECONDGETOBJ));
    fetchMock.get(`*`, JSON.stringify(THIRDGETOBJ));

    //...
}
```

The url for each `get` is the same, but the payload changes. However, using the code above I will get:

```
Error: Adding route with same name as existing route. See `overwriteRoutes` option.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `overwriteRoutes` option

```
test(`Created correctly`, async () => {
    fetchMock.get(`*`, JSON.stringify(FIRSTGETOBJ));
    fetchMock.get(`*`, JSON.stringify(SECONDGETOBJ), { overwriteRoutes: false });
    fetchMock.get(`*`, JSON.stringify(THIRDGETOBJ), { overwriteRoutes: false });

    //...
}
```

Comment: For me (fetch-mock@9.5.0), I had to include `{ repeat: 1 }` in each of the mock options - otherwise it would continue to give me the first result.